# Symfony 4.4 get logger service inside kernel

Tags: php, symfony

I am having issues getting the logger service.
I have a custom file that I am using.
I am loading a custom app kernel and booting it.

```
$kernel = new CustomKernel('dev', 'true'); 
$kernel->boot()
```

Now what I am trying to do is get the logger.

`$logger = $kernel->getContainer()->get('logger')` and I am not having it work.

I receive `ServiceNotFoundException` with message `"The "logger" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead."`.

I tried adding the service to `service.yml` file as well and set it as `public` but it doesnt work.

```
Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
      alias: 'logger'
      public: true
```

Comment: In your service definition, replace Psr\Log\LoggerInterface with 'my.logger'. Use `bin/console debug:container my.logger` to confirm the alias is public and then use it.  I would have expected your definition to have worked but the LoggerInterface is also used internally so I guess you override gets overridden elsewhere.